# Реализация унарного минуса в калькуляторе с++

Tags: c++, калькулятор

Всем доброго времени суток.

У меня есть небольшой калькулятор выражений.

Последовательность действий с выражением:

1. Пользователь его вводит
2. Оно проверяется на ошибки
3. Переводится в постфиксное
4. Считается

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <cmath>

   using namespace std;

   // Template Stack.
   template<class dataType>
   class Stack
   {
   private:
       int counter;
       int size = 10;
       dataType *arr = new dataType[size];
   public:
       Stack();
       Stack(const Stack &copy);
       ~Stack();
       void pushStack(dataType newElement);
       dataType popStack();
       void clearStack();
       bool isEmpty();
       int sizeOfStack();
       dataType operator[] (int index);
       Stack& operator= (const Stack &newArr);
   };

   template<class dataType>
   dataType Stack<dataType>::operator[] (int index)
   {
       return arr[index];
   }

   template<class dataType>
   Stack<dataType>& Stack<dataType>::operator= (const Stack& newArr)
   {
       if (this != &newArr)
       {
           if (arr != 0)
           {
               delete[]arr;
           }
           size = newArr.size;
           arr = new dataType[size];

           for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
           {
               arr[i] = newArr.arr[i];
           }
       }
       return *this;
   }

   template<class dataType>
   Stack<dataType>::Stack()
   {
       counter = 0;
   }

   template<class dataType>
   Stack<dataType>::~Stack()
   {
       delete[]arr;
   }

   template<class dataType>
   void Stack<dataType>::pushStack(dataType newElem)
   {
       arr[counter] = newElem;
       counter++;
       if (counter == size)
       {
           dataType *bufArr;
           bufArr = new dataType[size];
           size += 10;
           for (int i = 0; i < size - 10; i++)
           {
               bufArr[i] = arr[i];
           }
           delete[] arr;
           arr = nullptr;
           arr = new dataType[size];
           for (int i = 0; i < size - 10; i++)
           {
               arr[i] = bufArr[i];
           }
           delete[] bufArr;
           bufArr = nullptr;
       }
   }

   template<class dataType>
   dataType Stack<dataType>::popStack()
   {
       counter--;
       return arr[counter];
   }

   template<class dataType>
   bool Stack<dataType>::isEmpty()
   {
       return counter == 0;
   }

   template<class dataType>
   Stack<dataType>::Stack(const Stack &copy)
   {
       size = copy.size;
       arr = new dataType[size];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       {
           arr[i] = copy.arr[i];
       }
   }

   template<class dataType>
   int Stack<dataType>::sizeOfStack()
   {
       return counter;
   }

   template<class dataType>
   void Stack<dataType>::clearStack()
   {
       delete[] arr;

       size = 10;
       counter = 0;
       arr = new dataType[size];
   }

   // Calculator
   string changeToPostfix(string expression)
   {
       string result;
       Stack<char> st;

       size_t index = 0;

       while (index != expression.size())
       {
           char currentSymbol;
           currentSymbol = expression[index];
           int stackTop;
           switch (currentSymbol)
           {
           case '+':
           case '-':
               stackTop = st.sizeOfStack();
               while (stackTop != 0)
               {
                   char currentOperator;
                   currentOperator = st[stackTop - 1];
                   if (currentOperator != '(')
                   {
                       result += currentOperator;
                       st.popStack();
                       stackTop--;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }
               st.pushStack(currentSymbol);
               break;
           case '*':
           case '/':
               stackTop = st.sizeOfStack();
               while (stackTop != 0)
               {
                   char currentOperator;
                   currentOperator = st[stackTop - 1];
                   if (currentOperator == '^' || currentOperator == '*' || currentOperator == '/')
                   {
                       result += currentOperator;
                       st.popStack();
                       stackTop--;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       break;
                   }
               }
               st.pushStack(currentSymbol);
               break;
           case '(':
               st.pushStack(currentSymbol);
               break;
           case ')':
               stackTop = st.sizeOfStack();
               while (stackTop != 0)
               {
                   char currentOperator;
                   currentOperator = st.popStack();
                   stackTop--;
                   if (currentOperator == '(')
                   {
                       break;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       result += currentOperator;
                   }
               }
               break;
           case '^':
               st.pushStack(currentSymbol);
               break;
           default:
               if (isdigit(currentSymbol))
               {
                   int i = index;
                   result += '|';
                   while (isdigit(expression[i]))
                   {
                       result += expression[i];
                       i++;
                   }
                   index = i - 1;
               }
               else
               {
                   result += currentSymbol;
               }
               break;
           }
           index++;
       }
       int stackTop = st.sizeOfStack();
       while (stackTop != 0)
       {
           result += st.popStack();
           stackTop--;
       }
       return result;
   }

   bool checkExpression(string expression, char parameter)
   {
       bool checkResult = true;
       for (int i = 0; i < expression.size(); i++)
       {
           if (expression[i] == '(')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == ')')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == '+')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == '-')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == '*')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == '/')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == '^')
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == parameter)
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (isdigit(expression[i]))
           {
               continue;
           }
           else if (expression[i] == 'c' && expression[i + 1] == 'o' && expression[i + 2] == 's')
           {
               if (parameter == 'c' || parameter == 'o' || parameter == 's')
               {
                   checkResult = false;
                   break;
               }
               if (expression[i + 3] == '(')
               {
                   i += 3;
                   continue;
               }
               else
               {
                   checkResult = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
           else if (expression[i] == 's' && expression[i + 1] == 'i' && expression[i + 2] == 'n')
           {
               if (parameter == 's' || parameter == 'i' || parameter == 'n')
               {
                   checkResult = false;
                   break;
               }
               if (expression[i + 3] == '(')
               {
                   i += 3;
                   continue;
               }
               else
               {
                   checkResult = false;
                   break;
               }
           }
           else if (expression[i] == 't' && expression[i + 1] == 'g')
           {
               if (parameter == 't' || parameter == 'g')
               {
                   checkResult = false;
                   break;
               }
               if (expression[i + 2] == '(')
               {
                   i += 2;
                   continue;
               }

           }
           else
           {
               checkResult = false;
               break;
           }
       }
       return checkResult;
   }

   double calculate(string expression, char symbolParameter, string numberParameter)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < expression.size(); i++)
       {
           if (expression[i] == symbolParameter)
           {
               expression[i] = '|';
               expression.insert(i + 1, numberParameter);
           }
       }
       Stack<double> st;
       int index = 0;
       double currentNumber;
       while (index != expression.size())
       {
           char currentSymbol;
           currentSymbol = expression[index];
           string newNum;
           int posOfSymbol;

           if (expression[index] == 's' && expression[index + 1] == 'i' && expression[index + 2] == 'n')
           {
               posOfSymbol = index + 4;
               while (isdigit(expression[posOfSymbol]))
               {
                   newNum += expression[posOfSymbol];
                   posOfSymbol++;
               }
               currentNumber = sin(stoi(newNum));
               index = posOfSymbol - 1;
           }
           else if (expression[index] == 'c' && expression[index + 1] == 'o' && expression[index + 2] == 's')
           {
               posOfSymbol = index + 4;
               while (isdigit(expression[posOfSymbol]))
               {
                   newNum += expression[posOfSymbol];
                   posOfSymbol++;
               }
               currentNumber = cos(stoi(newNum));
               index = posOfSymbol - 1;
           }
           else if (expression[index] == 't' && expression[index + 1] == 'g')
           {
               posOfSymbol = index + 3;
               while (isdigit(expression[posOfSymbol]))
               {
                   newNum += expression[posOfSymbol];
                   posOfSymbol++;
               }
               if (cos(stoi(newNum)) != 0)
               {
                   currentNumber = sin(stoi(newNum)) / cos(stoi(newNum));
                   index = posOfSymbol - 1;
               }
               else
               {
                   cout << "Error: Div zero!" << endl;
                   throw "Error: Div zero!";
               }
           }
           else if (currentSymbol == '|')
           {
               int i = index + 1;
               while (isdigit(expression[i]))
               {
                   newNum += expression[i];
                   i++;
               }
               currentNumber = stoi(newNum);
               index = i - 1;
           }
           else
           {
               double leftNumber;
               double rightNumber;
               rightNumber = st.popStack();
               leftNumber = st.popStack();
               switch (currentSymbol)
               {
               case '+':
                   currentNumber = leftNumber + rightNumber;
                   break;
               case '-':
                   currentNumber = leftNumber - rightNumber;
                   break;
               case '*':
                   currentNumber = leftNumber * rightNumber;
                   break;
               case '/':
                   if (rightNumber != 0)
                   {
                       currentNumber = leftNumber / rightNumber;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       cout << "Error: Div zero!" << endl;
                       throw "Error: Div zero!";
                   }
                   break;
               case '^':
                   currentNumber = pow(leftNumber, rightNumber);
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
               }
           }
           st.pushStack(currentNumber);
           index++;
       }
       return st.popStack();
   }
   ```

   Мне нужно чтобы он считал выражения с унарным минусом.

   Как мне его(унарный минус) реализовать ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Унарный минус это символ `-` в начале выражения либо после любого знака операции либо после `(`.

Соответственно в функции `changeToPostfix()` анализируйте эти состояния и встретив `-` отправляйте в стек и `result` либо обычный (бинарный) `-` либо, скажем, символ `M` (и нужным образом интерпретируйте его в остальных частях программы).